# Installed MongoDB version does not match db.version()

Tags: mongodb

On my Mac I've just installed `MongoDB Community Server` version `4.2.0` which is the latest at the time of this post.

I've navigated to the downloaded `bin` folder and started `mongod` with a specified `dbpath`. It shows me `db version v4.0.4` on the terminal.

I also use `Robo 3T` as my database GUI and when I run `db.version()`, it returns `4.0.4`.

Why is it not showing `4.2.0`? `4.2.0` is the one I downloaded and am currently running via terminal. I've already tried terminating and starting `mongod` using `CTRL+C` in the terminal.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Can you show us how you downloaded mongodb version 4.2.0

Comment: @RaviShankarBharti I downloaded the `TGZ` for 4.2.0 from their website. Extracted the TGZ's contents to a folder in my `User` directory. Then using terminal, I navigate to the mongodb/bin folder and run mongod from there.

Comment: It is probably because you have installed both versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. It turns out that one of the packages I have on `brew` had installed an instance of mongodb as a dependency. I had to uninstall that mongodb instance from brew and now I'm getting the correct latest version. I'm on Mac OS by the way. Hope this helps anyone facing the same issue.